# Uber driver scheduling

Tags: uber-api

I have created a Uber app(Rides API) and using server token i can able to get
[Price](https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.625732&start_longitude=-122.377807&end_latitude=37.785114&end_longitude=-122.406677&server_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) and [Time](https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time?start_latitude=37.625732&start_longitude=-122.377807&end_latitude=37.785114&end_longitude=-122.406677&server_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) estimates.

How can I schedule a driver using Uber api?

Comment: By scheduling, do you refer to making a request for a ride or schedule one ahead of time? If you want to request a ride, check out the POST /requests endpoint as documented here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a request for a ride, you need to POST to /requests. Like agraebe said, you can find documentation on that endpoint [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests).

[This](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorials-rides-api) page also has a tutorial on requesting a ride, and the lifecycle of a request, walking you through step by step how requests work.